# Connect Multiple Yields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails Newbie. Be gentle. If I need to show more stuff I'll do it.

Trying to insert a newsletter signup block above my footer on a project but didn't make it a partial in the layouts set up.

I have the yield outputting an index from a blog.

Right now it's just saying "false" on my local host.

Is it possible to have multiple yields to different indexes?

Is it possible to insert another page into a layout page?

application.html.erb

```
<div id="blog">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
<div>
 <%= content_for?(:newsletter) ? yield(:newsletter) : yield %>
</div>
<div>
 <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
```

newsletter.html.erb

```
<% content_for :newsletter do %>
<h1>Get My Awesome News Letter</h1>
<p>Give me your email and keep up to date on my cat's thoughts.</p>
<%= form_tag('/emailapi/subscribe', method: "post", id: "subscribe", remote: "true") do -%>
   <%= email_field(:email, :address, {id: "email", placeholder: "email address"}) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Sign me up!") %>
<% end %>
```

emailapi_controller.rb

```
class EmailapiController < ApplicationController
def newsletter
    render params[:newsletter]
end

def subscribe
    gb = Gibbon::Request.new

    gb.lists.subscribe({
        :id => ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"],
        :email => {:email => params[:email][:address]}
        })
end
end
```

routes.rb

```
root to: 'posts#index'

get "/:newsletter" => 'emailapi#newsletter'
post 'emailapi/subscribe' => 'emailapi#subscribe'
```

Comment: You shouldn't need this conditional test: `content_for?(:newsletter) ? yield(:newsletter) : yield ` try just: `<%= content_for :newsletter %>` which basically does the above for you :) (note the `<%=` matters) http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need this conditional test:

```
content_for?(:newsletter) ? yield(:newsletter) : yield
```

try just:

```
<%= content_for :newsletter %>
```

Here's the doc on `content_for`:

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for

Ie only show the newsletter if newsletter is present.
The extra yield (if newsletter-content is not present) is repeated from the blog-section above.
You probably shouldn't have duplicate plain `yield`s just the one... everything else should have a name (eg `:newsletter`)

Also - you seem to be missing an `<% end %>` in newsletter.html.erb

Comment: Didn't help. Made the recommended adjustments to the the other yield but in the end, I just put in the _footer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use another render block. I'm not sure where your `newsletter.html.erb` lives, but if, for example it lived in a folder such as `includes/` you could do something like:

`<%= render 'includes/newsletter' %>`